# Algorithm for finding near duplicate videos

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, image-processing, hash

I have a folder of twitch clips from streams  - some are near-duplicates, for instance one may be 5 seconds longer than the other however still catches an identical action that occurs in the stream.

I'm trying to make an algortihm in python to detect these duplicates. Firstly, since we know the duplicates will capture some identical action, I found the first and last frame of the shortest video, and used pHash to cross-check those frames with every frame in the longest video.

This works, however the process takes a long time and I'm looking for something that can find duplicates in maybe 30 seconds, as there might be 5+ duplicates in the folder.

Comment: This is too broad for the site.  Please check out the [help/on-topic] to see which types of questions are appropriate for stack overflow.